# Error while running apache bench ,could not open post data ,the filename ,directory name , or volume label syntax is in

Tags: apachebench

I am trying to run a scenario using  apache benchmark ( ab) 
My current path is D:\ecif-documents\performance. 
Post data file corp_sample.json is in the same directory .
I am running my test case on windows.

All the syntax's, i tried , are giving error . Any inputs ?

*Method 1 :*

```
ab -n 5 -p "file:///D:/cif-documents/performance/corp_sample.json" -T "application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/corporates/enrollcorporate?access_token=lsM7Ar3FqX4pO36ORAqI3q0Km3OPioyLYougQSD8oVtXI4mAXPU5jocZx9QJKYcz" -v 4
```

**Error -ab: Could not open POST data file (file:///D:/cif-documents/performance/corp_sample.json): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

*Method 2:*

```
D:\ecif-documents\performance>ab -n 5 -p "corp_sample.json" -T "application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/corporates/enrollcorporate?access_token=lsM7Ar3FqX4pO36ORAqI3q0Km3OPioyLYougQSD8oVtXI4mAXPU5jocZx9QJKYcz" -v 4
```

**Error : Could not stat POST data file (corp_sample.json): Partial results are valid but processing is incomplete**

*Method 3:*

```
D:\ecif-documents\performance>ab -n 5 -p "D:\cif-documents\performance\corp_sample.json" -T "application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/corporates/enrollcorporate?access_token=lsM7Ar3FqX4pO36ORAqI3q0Km3OPioyLYougQSD8oVtXI4mAXPU5jocZx9QJKYcz" -v 4
```

**Error : 
ab: Could not open POST data file (D:\cif-documents\performance\corp_sample.json): The system cannot find the path specified.**

```
*Method 4*
    D:\ecif-documents\performance>ab -n 5 -p "http://localhost:3000/corp_sample.json" -T "application/json" "http://localhost:3000/api/corporates/enrollcorporate?access_token=lsM7Ar3FqX4pO36ORAqI3q0Km3OPioyLYougQSD8oVtXI4mAXPU5jocZx9QJKYcz" -v 4
```

**Error : ab: Could not open POST data file (http://localhost:3000/corp_sample.json): The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I am able to open the url (http://localhost:3000/corp_sample.json) in browser and see the json .

Comment: Hello Tanmay, did you solve this problema, because I have the same problem

Comment: @Jean . no i moved to using other tools autocannon from nearform.

Comment: Hey @TanmayPatil, how did you manage to attach the post json file in autocannon? Cannot figure that out.